# Regex for matching label excluding forward /

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I am trying to make a syntax highlighter for JCL (Job Control Language) for sublime text. In that I need to match some "label" of type

```
//label
```

I am using

```
\/\/[A-Za-z0-9]*
```

for matching it, but it also includes "//" in the highlighter. Can anyone help me to make a regex which match the label following "//" but excludes "//" in the highlighted part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookbehinds (although I don't know if available in your programming language). The syntax would be something like:

```
(?<=\/\/)[A-Za-z0-9]*
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use capturing groups

```
\/\/([A-Za-z0-9]*)
```

Now the result without the // will be saved in capturing group 0 (or 1 depening on where you are doing this)

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookbehind or `\K` (*which discards the previously matched characters from printing*)

```
\/\/\K[A-Za-z0-9]*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bW3pG2/2)